# How can I use Academicons in ConTeXt?

Tags: fonts, symbols, context, academicons

I found a way to use symbols in ConText including fontawesome, but Ican't find any examples that uses Academicons in ConTeXt. Can anyone provide a short example? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### For one document

If you only need Academicons in one document, the following may be simple enough:

```
%Self-explanatory
\definefontsynonym[academicons][file:academicons.ttf] %Assuming it installed
%Here we define our new symbol set using the Academicons font
\startsymbolset[academicons][font=academicons]
\stopsymbolset
%Optional shortcut for the lazy ones
\def\Academicons#1{\symbol[academicons][#1]}
\starttext
¡Larga vida a \symbol[academicons][sci-hub] y \symbol[academicons][stackoverflow]!

Does \Academicons{overleaf} support \CONTEXT?
\stoptext
```

[image]

### Writing a new symbol set for ConTeXt

On the other hand, if you want to be able to load Academicons via `\usesymbols[academicons]`, let's create a `symb-imp-academicons.mkiv` file (the `symb-imp-` prefix is mandatory). I'm using the FontAwesome library by Wolfgang Schuster as a template.

```
%D \module
%D   [       file=symb-imp-academicons,
%D        version=2021.08.13,
%D          title=\CONTEXT\ Symbol Libraries,
%D       subtitle=Academicons (1.9.1),
%D         author=Jairo A. del Rio,
%D           date=\currentdate,
%D      copyright=Jairo A. del Rio]

\definefontsynonym[academicons][file:academicons.ttf]

\startsymbolset[academicons][font=academicons]
\stopsymbolset

% From now on, this is optional but allows you to generate a nice sample document.

\continueifinputfile{symb-imp-academicons.mkiv}

\usemodule[article-basic]

\starttext

    \startnamedsection[title][title={Academicons}]
        \showsymbolset[academicons]
    \stopnamedsection

\stoptext
```

Now save your file in `texmf-local` in your standalone/TeX Live distribution, and then run

```
mtxrun --generate
context --make
```

from your command line. You'll be able to load Academicons just by invoking it in any document:

```
\usesymbols[academicons]
\def\Academicons#1{\symbol[academicons][#1]}
\starttext
¡Larga vida a \symbol[academicons][sci-hub] y \symbol[academicons][stackoverflow]!

Does \Academicons{overleaf} support \CONTEXT?
\stoptext
```

I recommend you to take a look to other `symb-imp-...` files in your ConTeXt distribution so you can figure out how to write your own one.

Comment: Wow thank you so much for the very kind and detailed answer!